# Animate fragments content before closing it

Tags: android, animation, fragment

I am displaying a `FrameLayout` with some components inside a `Fragment`. In `onCreateView(..)` I am animating the content of the `FrameLayout` and everything works fine. Now I want to animate the content before closing the `Fragment`.

In my current solution I am overriding `onBackPressed()` in the parent `Activity` and then I'm calling the method `onBackPressed()` inside my `Fragment` and animating the content there. The problem with this solution is, that I want to inflate the `Fragment` from various activities and then this is not really a nice solution... Does anybody know a better approach?

Thanks for your help!

**Note:**

I also tried to override `onCreateView()` and `onPause()` but the animation is not shown if I start it in those methods

and the following method does not fulfill my requirements either as it animates the whole fragment and I want to animate the content

```
getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_up, R.anim.slide_out_up, R.anim.slide_out_down, R.anim.slide_in_down)
```

Comment: What is wrong with `onDestroyView()` of the `Fragment` itself?

Comment: I already tried animating the content in `onDestroyView()`and `onPause()` but it's not working in both of them..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can try to handle `onBackPressed` in your `fragment` like below:

```
    yourRootLayout.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    yourRootLayout.requestFocus();
    yourRootLayout.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

            if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP && keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){
                animateMyViews();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: that worked thank you! I only changed one thing: I replaced getView() with my rootLayout because getView() returned null in onCreateView

Comment: sure. sorry i forget to add my code example should run in onResume

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to perform sliding exit animation before dismissing the view/fragment.
These are the steps I performed:

1. I created a runnable task which can dismiss the current screen.
2. Passed that runnable to animating view.
3. Used view.postOnAnimationDelayed(runnable, 400) so that it can animate and execute the runnable after 400 milliseconds.
4. Also I made sure that my animation duration is >= 400 so that the transition is smooth.

Below is a little bit altered version of code for idea.

I used view.postOnAnimationDelayed(runnable, 400) to

```html
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity(), getTheme()) {
            @Override
            public void onBackPressed() {
                ParentFragment.this.onBackPressed();
                Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        //Referencing this class in runnable
                        getInstance().dismiss();
                    }
                };
             
             //webView is the child view loaded on this fragment
             if(webView != null && webView.webViewClient != null) {
                webView.webViewClient.animateClose(webView, runnable);
             } else {
                super.dismiss();
             }
        };
```

function animateOnClose in webViewClient looked like this:

```html
public void animateClose(final WebView view, Runnable runnable) {
  Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getMainActivityContext(),
               animationResource);
        view.startAnimation(anim);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
            view.postOnAnimationDelayed(runnable, 400);
            // you can also try view.postOnAnimation(runnable);
        } else {
            runnable.run();
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is to notify the `Fragment` that you are about to destroy it.

A crude pseudocode might look like

```
myFragment.aboutToClose();
```

While in your `Fragment`'s `aboutToClose()` method.

```
public void aboutToClose()
{
    //  Perform all the animations you want.
    //  Don't forget to add onAnimationEnd() call back.

    onAnimationEnd()
    {
        // Notify Activity that Animations have completed.
        callback.animationsCompleted();
    }
}
```

Finally in your calling `Activity`.

```
public void animationsCompleted()
{
    //  Destroy fragment.
    getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()
        .beginTransaction()
        .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_up, R.anim.slide_out_up, R.anim.slide_out_down, R.anim.slide_in_down);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I was looking for a solution, where I don't need to change any code in the activity because I want to inflate the fragment from various activities